SonarSource Rule S2139 Triggered in Program.cs (C#)
I've encountered an issue with SonarSource's Rule S2139 (Exceptions should be either logged or rethrown but not both).
According to the S2139 rule description:

When an exception is logged and rethrown, the upstream code may not be aware that the exception has already been logged. As a result, the same exception gets logged multiple times, making it difficult to identify the root cause of the issue. This can be particularly problematic in multi-threaded applications where messages from other threads can be interwoven with the repeated log entries.

However, in my case, the code smell is detected in Program.cs, which is the most upstream code. In the code, I'm catching exceptions and logging the error message as follows:
try
{
    // omitting code
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    logger.LogError(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    logger.LogInformation("**** SHUTDOWN Program ****");
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}

Am I misunderstanding the rule, or could this be a false positive? I'm aware of the "False Positive" and "Won't Fix" options in SonarQube or suppressing the warning, but I would like to confirm my understanding before proceeding.
Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

It's not a false positive. You are doing exactly what the rule says. In your catch block you are logging the Exception and then rethrowing it. If this is your "outermost" code, then why bother the user with a crash?

@Fildor, The purpose of throwing the exception in my case is to alert me immediately when something goes wrong, instead of checking the logs. (It is ASP.NET, and the observability tool will alert me immediately when exceptions are thrown). This approach helps me to respond more quickly and efficiently to any issues that come up.

In that case it's still not a false positive. It detected a smell it was supposed to detect. Now, you consider this a wanted behavior. So, muting the warning (for this specific piece of code) would probably be the easiest/quickest resolve.

I don't think that Sonar is clever enough to know that Program.cs is your top level of code hence the warning, but given that your try / catch / finally block is at that top level is there any point in throwing this exception?
Assuming all the interesting stuff is happening inside of the try then your program can exit gracefully having logged the issue as best as possible simply by removing the throw from inside the catch.

The purpose of throwing the exception in my case is to alert me immediately when something goes wrong, instead of checking the logs. This approach helps me to respond more quickly and efficiently to any issues that come up.

But your program will immediately exit on exception, logging the reason along the way. What more of an alert do you need?

Also: How do you get alerted in case of an exception? Could you move that notification trigger into that catch block?

@ste-fu, It is ASP.NET, and the observability tool will alert me immediately when exceptions are thrown, instead of checking error logs.

I might suggest that you could fire off a custom event for your observability tool as well rather than throwing the exception, but ultimately Sonar is intended as a guide to help you avoid common pitfalls, not as the ultimate arbiter of acceptable code.

@ste-fu I generally agree with you. However, another consequence of killing an exception is that the deployment may appear successful, even when there's an issue within the Program.cs file. Allowing the server to display a significantly flawed screen will make it clear to everyone that there's a problem. An exception is not your enemy, but rather your friend.

Well, generally, a runtime exception could happen at any time. So, if it happens while you are still on your predeployment slot, that's convenient. There might be cleaner ways to go about that, though. But if that's how you like it and it's working for you - why not? Mute the warning.
